# How do I scan for multiple BLE services simultaneously with iOS CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to find a good way for my iOS app to scan for three different types of Bluetooth LE peripherals, each represented by a unique service/UUID. The CBCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options methods takes an array of service UUIDs and the documentation states that "the central manager returns only peripherals that advertise the services you specify" when this is provided.  However I found that what this actually means is that if you specify 3 service UUIDs, you will get only the peripherals that advertise all three of those services. i.e. it's an AND not an OR: it will not return all of the peripherals that advertise ANY of those services in the array.

The only other option that I see is to pass a 'nil' for the array of service UUIDs, and per the documentation "all discovered peripherals are returned regardless of their supported services (not recommended)".  I could then filter for any of the three service UUIDs I am looking for. But Apple seems to be dissuading me from doing this by telling me it is not recommended. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't recommend the use of `nil` because it isn't as efficient and can impact battery life.

The solution is simply to create three `CBCentralManager` instances and have each instance scan for a different service.  You can even use the same delegate instance because the `CBCentralManager` instance is passed to the delegate methods.